# Shared filesystem between KVMs

Tags: kvm-virtualization, iscsi, shared-storage

If I want to have shared fs between multiple kvm machines what is the best way to go when I'm already using ceph.

I accessing my kvm disks directly through rbd devices but with ext4 on top of this even if I would add "shared" disks which are accessible with multiple vm this would not work with ext4.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're game, you can use CephFS, or setup a VM, backed by an RBD volume, to act as an NFS server to your other machines.  You're completely right that sharing an ext4 formatted RBD volume amongst multiple machines will definitely end in tears.

Comment: NFS is not an option in my case, not just because of the additional overhead but the software which would run on top of it (dropbox replacement) would have issues with it. Yes I will definitely look into using CephFS if we have ceph running already why to bring another technology in.

Answer (score 0):

To sharing a filesystem, you had to use a clustered filesystem. The clustered filesystem of choice in a Linux environment generally is GFS2, but it is not the only one available.

Sharing filesystem and, more in general, storage resources is a complicated task - be sure to document yourself before putting a similar setup into production. And **test** any changes before propagating them to production systems.

A simpler (but lower-performance) approach would be to use NFS to share a common storage resource, and mounting it on the various virtualization node. Please keep in mind that a loopback NFS mount (eg: a localhost mount) was not 100% supported under Linux until recent kernels (it works, but not in a stable manner due to some livelock problems).